# Xamarin iOS development isn't running on my iPhone

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I am currently trying to develop an iOS app using Xamarin. I do not have an Apple Developer account but I read on the Xamarin website that I don't need an Apple Developer account to provision my phone onto my apple id.
I am using both a Windows 10 computer running Visual Studio Community 2015 and a MacBook Pro with both Xamarin Studio and X-code installed. I can connect my two devices, I am just unable to access the provisioning profile to run my project from Visual Studio, through the MacBook, to my phone.
I have been able to create a provisioning profile for an app on xcode but my app on xamarin still does not have a profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin have created an easy to follow guide, works great!

[Free Provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)

Pay attention to step 6. You can really only go wrong there.

"make sure that the Bundle Identifier matches exactly the Bundle Identifier of your Xamarin.iOS app and ensure the deployment target matches or is lower than your connected iOS device"

Also, make sure you click "Fix Issue" described in step 8. I use this all the time for multiple projects with no problem and I have the same setup running VS2015 from win10 to a macbook pro, the phone i use is an iPhone 6s+.